# How can i use jquery datepicker with struts 2 theme css_xhtml?

Tags: jquery-plugins, struts2

I am using struts 2.1.8.1 and if i use struts2-jquery-plugin.2.2.2 datepicker dosn't appear. if i use struts2-jquery-plugin-2.0.0 it apperars but i can't use it with theme css_xhtml. Is there a way to solve this? I want to use it with css_xhtml theme.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately No. DateTimePicker component would not be available css_XTHML theme. This component would be available in AJAX themes.